# socket timeout exception on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, solr

We have solr router and shards. This appears in the jetty log of the router when doing faceted search across all the shards.

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry 
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error 
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry 
INFO: Retrying request
```

followed by exception about Internal Server Error. We run eighty shards distributed across several servers. Router runs on its own node.

UPD:
In the HttpCommComponent class of SOLR which sumbits requests to shards using HttpClient class I have noticed the following set on the MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager:
    mgr.getParams().setDefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost(20);

it seems to me like too little setting for 80+ shards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more debugging I have found out, that one of the requests had a size of 4,4MB. The default maxPostSize in tomcat6 is 2MB (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/ajp.html).

Changing that to 10MB has greatly improved situation on the solr side.